# Rust Error When Passing Reference to TCPListener

Tags: rust

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

pub struct Server {
    addr: String,
}

impl Server{
    pub fn new(addr: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            addr: addr
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self) { // can make this (self) since we can give ownership of addr to run function.
        println!("Listening on: {}", self.addr);
        
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(self.addr);
    }

}
```

I am new to rust so please forgive the ignorance. I am trying to pass a reference of self.addr to the TcpListener but it is throwing this error:

```
cannot move out of `self.addr` which is behind a shared reference
move occurs because `self.addr` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

When I change it to

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind(&self.addr);
```

it works.
I thought that &self was already a reference to the variable self.addr which I am trying to use. So why do I need to reference it again for the TcpListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is a reference. `self.addr` is not.

When you access `self.addr`, you dereference `self`. `self.addr` has type `String`, not `&String`. If you want a reference (or to not move it), you need to take a reference explicitly.